# Is it possible if I don't want to mention exact name of input file when doing any ffmpeg conversion

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been using the following command to create a video from a still image and an audio file and it's awesome. I love it very much.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 5 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4
```

However, I still think it would be good if I don't have to write a command to match the exact file name of either the picture or audio here.

What I do every day is I have to copy one image file and an audio file into my folder. Then I have to rename each image and audio file to something short like the ones above so it's easy for me to write the command line like that.

But what if I have an image file name that is complicated like 8oerlujsfljsdl.jpg and I just want to start converting it right away without renaming it or have to write this full long name in command line?

Is there such a thing as `-i *.jpg` which means any image file in this folder (I assure I will have only one image and one audio in the folder) will be used as input file and convert.

Sorry for such a long question which could be unnecessary but I just don't know how to explain my issue in short. I hope it could be understood.

Comment: `Is there such a thing as -i *.jpg` have you tried `-i *.jpg`?

Comment: This might be better suited for PowerUser.

Comment: @tkausl yes I did try but it didn't work and this is what I got 

Could find no file with path '*.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
*.jpg: No such file or directory.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, Windows 10, mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something to get you started. Using a wildcard/variable for all '.jpg' in the current folder. This example assumes 'audio.mp3' is also in same folder.

1. Open 'Notepad'.
2. Copy the code below into 'Notepad'.
3. Save as 'convert.bat' (or whatever - but make sure it's .bat) into same folder.
4. Double-Click the '.bat' file.

> for %%a in ("*.jpg") do ffmpeg -framerate 5 -loop 1 -i "%%a" -i
>   audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p
>   "%%~na.mp4"
>
> pause

The above should get you started, at least with multiple pictures. If you want to extend things to include multiple/random audio files search around for some 'FFMPEG' scripting/batch examples, there are many.

Lastly, I don't know the size (dimensions) of the pictures you are working with, this could be important in terms of compatibility. Large photos will produce H.264 high 'Profile' and 'Level' settings that may prevent your output files playing on some devices. If that becomes a concern, it may be worth adding a resize filter to bring the photo/video down to 1080p/720p to allow greater compatibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed and helpful answer. It works. For the photo, I always use 1280x720 which works just fine. 

By the way, is it also possible to do the same for the audio file name? Really sorry, I should have asked this from the beginning.

Comment: If it works, and answers your question, you should mark my answer as answered. As for your further questions I'll have a check, but for now, it's been a long day, I'm in bed.... :-)

Comment: Yes, let me mark it as answered and I hope you can help me explore it further. Thanks very much again for your great answer.